# iOS Swift How to pass JSON String and Array or Dictionary to Javascript from UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

In my project I have pass String to JavaScript using **stringByEvaluatingJavaScript** it have passed successfully. But if I have pass JSON String and Array or Dictionary means it doesn't pass the values I don't know how to pass these.

Here I have mention the code I have tried for pass the string to JavaScript,

```
let param:String = "HI"
let _ = self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "myNewFunction('\(param)')")
```

It Successfully return the value **HI**

Here I Mentioned the JavaScript Code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <p>Click the button to display an alert box.</p>
    <script>
        function myNewFunction(param) {
            alert(param);
        }
    </script>
<body>
    <button onclick="myNewFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I pass the values like Array and Dictionary and the JSON String?

Comment: Why you do not convert your dictionary to jsonstring using jsonserializer ? Then you can pass the json string to your javascript method.

Comment: How, Can you please say?@HuseinBehboodiRad

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
let dict:[String:Any] = ["key1":10,"key2":false, "key3": "Some string goes in here"]
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: [.prettyPrinted])
        if let data = jsonData{
            let value = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print( value )
        }
```

**Output:**
Optional("{\n  \"key1\" : 10,\n  \"key2\" : false,\n  \"key3\" : \"Some string goes in here\"\n}")

**Code in Playground**
[image]

**Result in Playground**
[image]

Here what was missing was the dictionary type inference i.e dict:[String:Any]. Also when you use try use optional along with it as it may throw an exception like try?

Answer (score 0):

This might work.. I haven't tested it yet:

```
if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrayOrDictionaryHere, options: [.prettyPrinted]), let param = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "myNewFunction('\(param)')")
}


//JS:

function myNewFunction(param) {
    alert(JSON.parse(param))
}
```

Comment: This code working only for String Value not for other things.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for converting dictionary to jsonstring:

```
 var dict : Dictionary = ["key1":"value1","key2":"value2"]
let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: [.prettyPrinted])
let value = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

and then call your javascript method using the string in `value`

if you replace `dict` in second line with and instance of json array then you will get json string of the json array too. I every thing will work for that too.

Comment: This code working only for String Value not for other things.

Comment: As I told you can convert your dictionary and array to string and then pass them to your javascript and in your javascript then convert the to array or dictionary.

Comment: OK. so in witch part you have the problem? In getting the json string in value or on receiving it on the java script? Can you see the json string in the value or not?

Comment: I have Used the below code only bro,  let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: tempComponentArray, options: [.prettyPrinted])
                let value = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                let encodedStr = self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "myNewFunction('\(String(describing: value))')")
                print("encodedStr: ",encodedStr!)

Comment: when I print the value means that returns empty.. print("encodedStr: ",encodedStr!)

Comment: tempComponentArray is an array or an arry into a dictionray? Please notice that you must put this array into a dictionary and then convert it to string. Jsonserializer need a json array to convert into string

Comment: But when I change options: [.prettyPrinted] to options: [ ] means it displays weird values like: [object Object], [object Object] .